# Manhwa where a pink haired main character goes back to the past

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manhwa is about a pink haired main character who used to be a bully but her boyfriend doesn't like bullies so they broke up. Years later the main character regretted what she did and she died but goes back to the past to get together with her boyfriend and be a nice person.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was the story set in modern times?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Blind to you](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/blind-to-you)*.

> Karen, who used to be known as **the #1 bully at her school, was abandoned by a boy she loved**. However, who would have thought an unexpected fate would happen to her!

As in the synopsis, the main character is a bully. She has a boyfriend, but he breaks up with her while she's in the middle of tormenting a girl who did better than her on a test.

Three years later, she is killed during a burglary, and wakes up while she's still in school, before she ever met her boyfriend.

[image: In school, after reincarnation]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Bullying` and `Reincarnated in the Past`.